# Find the difference between the dates and group it under some category

Tags: c++, date, unix

I have a start date and an end date. I need to find the difference between these dates and group it under the following categories.

< 1 year, < 2 year and so on till X years.

I'm trying to write a unix C++ program for this problem.
I can easily find the unix time difference between start and end date and compare with the 1 year's time stamp (12 * 30 * 20 * 60 * 60)  and so on.

Is there any C++ function that returns the difference in years given the start and end date? Also let's say, the difference is 8 years, I suppose I have to write conditions like this,

```
if((end_date - start_date) < 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
   group = " less than 1 year"
...
...
```

Until what point do I stop at, as I won't know what the maximum difference is between the dates?

Is there any easy way to compute this?

I know i'm confusing here, but i ve put all my efforts to explain the problem here. Thanks in advance. 
Also note, this is not a assignment or anything.

Comment: What about `std::chrono::duration`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Comment: I don't think there is any function defined in C++ libraries as of now but you can add it easily.

Comment: @ skynet : can you please give some idea on how it can be done easily?

Comment: Does it matter if the year is precise or not (365 days in a year, but some years are 366, which would have to be taken into account if you want it precisely). And define a constant for "seconds in a day" as 86400 (result of 24 * 60 * 60), makes is MUCH easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "precise years" (in other words, all years are 365 days long) is not an issue, I would do something like this (counting the number of times each year happens in this case - since the original question doesn't really say WHAT to do with each year)

```
const int MAX_YEARS = 10;
const int YEAR_IN_SECONDS = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;

std::array<int, MAX_YEARS+1> bins;

int years = static_cast<int>(difftime(end_date - start_date) / YEAR_IN_SECONDS);

// Outside of range, put it at the end of range... 
// We could discard or do something else in this case.
if (years > MAX_YEARS)
{
    years = MAX_YEARS;
}
bins[years]++;    // Seen one more of "this year".
```

Obviously, what you do with "bins", and what/how you store data there really depends on what you actually are trying to achieve.

An alternative solution would be to use `const double YEAR_IN_SECONDS = 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60;`, which would slightly better cover for leap-years. If you want to be precise about it, you'd have to find out if you are before or after each of the leapday in a particular year that is divisible by 4 (and keep in mind that there are special cases for years divisible by 100 and other rules at 400).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <chrono>

using years = std::chrono::duration<std::chrono::system_clock::rep, std::ratio<365 * 24 * 60 * 60, 1>>;

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point end_date = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start_date = end_date - years(2);

years how_many = std::chrono::duration_cast<years>(end_date - start_date);

int how_many_as_int = how_many.count();

std::cout << how_many_as_int << std::endl;

std::unordered_map<int, std::list<whatever>> m;
m[how_many_as_int].push_back(...);
```